# Sending 'CGFloat' (aka 'float') to parameter incompatible type 'CGSize' (aka 'struct CGSize')

Tags: objective-c, parameters, struct

I'm using the latest version of xcode 5.

I get this error twice in the following code:

```
 + (SemiSecretFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)name
            size:(CGFloat) size;
 {
 //dynamically search for a class with this name
 Class klass = NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Font", name]);
 //NSLog(@"looking for font: %@", name);
 //  NSLog(@"klass: %@", klass);
 SemiSecretFont * font = nil;
 if (klass)
font = [[[klass alloc] initWithSize:size] autorelease]; //error occurs here
 return font;
}

 - (id) fontWithSize:(CGFloat)s
 {
   Class klass = [self class];
   SemiSecretFont * f = nil;
   f = [[[klass alloc] initWithSize:s] autorelease]; //error occurs here again
   return f;
 }
```

The error: Sending 'CGFloat' (aka 'float') to parameter incompatible type 'CGSize' (aka 'struct CGSize')

I also get a warning: Multiple methods named 'initWithSize:' found

Update:

Here's my initWithSize declaration code...

```
 //this is not meant to be instantiated directly!
 - (id) initWithSize:(CGFloat)fontsize
 {
   if ((self = [super init])) {
   size = fontsize;
   font = nil;
 }
 return self;
 }
```

Comment: Show how you declared the `initWithSize:` method. It appears you made the parameter have a type of `CGSize` but in both places you are passing a `CGFloat`.

Comment: @maddy - Code updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be from https://github.com/ericjohnson/canabalt-ios, and

```
+ (SemiSecretFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)name size:(CGFloat) size;
```

seems to be a factory method, that returns an instance of `SemiSecretFont` or some
subclass. But when compiling

```
font = [[[klass alloc] initWithSize:size] autorelease]; //error occurs here
```

the compiler does not know that `kclass` is the `SemiSecretFont` class (or a subclass) which has
a method

```
- (id) initWithSize:(CGFloat)fontsize;
```

Theoretically, it could be an instance of [`NSTextContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSTextContainer_Class_TextKit/Reference/Reference.html), which has the method

```
- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size; // designated initialiser
```

To resolve that ambiguity, you can add an explicit cast:

```
font = [[(SemiSecretFont *)[klass alloc] initWithSize:size] autorelease];
```

Comment: Ok so now both instances of initWithSize looks like this:

     `// font = [[[klass alloc] initWithSize:size] autorelease];
     font = [[(SemiSecretFont *)[klass alloc] initWithSize:size] autorelease];`



       `//f = [[[klass alloc] initWithSize:s] autorelease];
       font = [[(SemiSecretFont *)[klass alloc] initWithSize:size] autorelease];`

with a warning on the second instance: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'CGFontRef' (aka 'struct CGFont *') from 'SemiSecretFont *'

Comment: @user3290191: In the second instance, it should be `f = ...`, not `font = ...` :-)

Comment: Great, that fixed it up!  Now I am getting a Thread breakpoint at this line (same code):

`Class klass = NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Font", name]);`

In the console, I get: 2014-03-17 15:02:07.439 [31354:70b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
(lldb)

Comment: @user3290191: That is a completely different problem, and if you google for that error message you should find solutions. If not, you are welcome to post a new question.